# orbd command not found

Tags: bash, solaris, corba

I am a newbie to Corba and so please excuse me if this question sounds silly!!

I am trying to run Corba Server on Solaris machine and getting the below exception.

```
WARNING: "IOP00410201: (COMM_FAILURE) Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: localhost; port: 1050"
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
```

On searching for Minor code 201 on Internet, I came to know that it could happen if Corba NamingService is not running and also it mentioned that use below command to start it

```
orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050
```

When I run it, I am getting

**-bash orbd: command not found**

I am not understanding how to resolve this. Please help.

Comment: Do you know the complete path of ordb? Then use the complete path.

Comment: I agree wtih Sriharsha. Are you sure the port is 1050. Shouldn't it be less than 1024?   When using Solaris software, you must become root to start a process on a port under 1024. http://www.informatik.hs-furtwangen.de/doku/java/j2sdk-1_4_1-doc/guide/idl/orbd.html . Run "whereis orbd" and "which orbd" and use that full path for running the file.

Comment: On my Linux machine, orbd exists within JAVA/JDK.. at /production/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/orbd. Try this full path what you get on your machine (after running whereis and which commands) OR see if JAVA/JDK on SunOS have this orbd file in it.

Comment: On a Solaris machine, you might find orbd under /opt/app/oracle/{product, Middleware}... or /opt/system/xx_Recommended/... etc locations. Basically where you have oracle installed $ORACLE_HOME. Does PATH variable has $ORACLE_HOME in it on your machine? Other locations might include: /usr/bin/orbd
/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.5.0/bin/orbd
/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.5.0/bin/sparcv9/orbd
/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.5.0/jre/bin/orbd
/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.5.0/jre/bin/sparcv9/orbd
/usr/j2se/bin/orbd
/usr/j2se/bin/sparcv9/orbd
/usr/j2se/jre/bin/orbd
/usr/j2se/jre/bin/sparcv9/orbd